# Tests under TestDriven.NET not picking up updated fuslogvw settings

Tags: .net, assembly-resolution, testdriven.net, assembly.load, fuslogvw

If there's a dup of this, I'll be upvoting it but until someone finds it for me.... This is a Things I've Learned Today [that nobody seems to have blogged about] entry...

With TestDriven.NET, I was continually getting the following output from an `Assembly.Load` :

> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>
> To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value >[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>
> To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

So I loaded fuslogvw, and as I'm on an x64 system, even tried the x64 version of same, but couldnt get it to display the log, no matter how many times I retried. I verified the settings in the registry, and everything seemed as it should be - `EnableLog` was set, but still no joy on the re-run.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the value of the setting gets cached within the process, and as TestDriven.net keeps a process (ProcessInvocation.exe) hanging around to provide a quick startup, it doesnt pick it up without one clicking on the tray icon (red pitchfork) and selecting Stop [to trigger a reload on the next run]. So now, I get:

```
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 2.0\ProcessInvocation.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
```

...

```
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
```

Just as desired...